# How to construct a rect structure in matlab giving four point's using ginput

Tags: image, matlab, crop

I'm trying to build a `rect` structure with 4 points received by the function `ginput` to make a crop of the image by that rectangle.

I have something like this:

```
[x,y] = ginput(4);
input_points = [x(1) y(1); x(2) y(2); x(3) y(3); x(4) y(4)];
...

disp([round(x(1)) round(x(2)) round(abs(x(2)-x(1))) round(abs(y(4)-y(1)))]);
image = imcrop(image,[round(x(1)) round(x(2)) round(abs(x(2)-x(1))) round(abs(y(4)-y(1)))]);
```

But does not work, the values displayed are too large.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
rec=round([min(x), min(y), max(x)-min(x), max(y)-min(y)]);
image2 = imcrop(image,rec);
```